# Will a "visa run" work in Mongolia?

Tags: us-citizens, mongolia, visa-runs, tourism

[Mongolian Embassy website says](http://mongolianembassy.us/visa-information-for-us-citizen-only/):

> “US citizens can travel to Mongolia without visa if his/her duration
> of stay is less than 90”

But I don’t find anything like the Schengen “within 180 days.”  Is there any such time one must stay away?  If I am approaching day ninety and there’s still “so much more to see and do,” **is it legal to leave and come back the next day?**  (Technically not a “visa run” if arriving without a visa, but what else can I call it?)

Text on their website shows limitations in English proficiency, so I hesitate to ask them and risk being suspected of wanting to abuse the system.  They already told me that to stay longer than ninety days, one must get a visa before arrival (when I asked if one could do it in-country).  So maybe “out and in” ***is*** an abuse, even if legal.

Comment: While I have no idea how it works for visa-free stays, for extensions of stay, an extension of 30 days is possible in Mongolia, but another extension is only possible 90 days after the end of the previous extension period (outside Mongolia). So probably it is not looked favourably.

Comment: Looking a TIMATIC, the wording is right. However, a visa run is never a good thing to do

Comment: Some rationale or a citation might be useful.  MANY people in central America have been doing it for years and publicly suggesting it.  I know some countries "frown on it" but some (apparently) don’t. But I have no intention of using it as a sneaky way to residency.  If I wanted to move there (I don’t), the "proper way" doesn't seem to be too expensive.  So, really, I’m just wondering whether it is legal.

Comment: Interestingly, Wikipedia states that “_Visitors from any country planning to stay in Mongolia for more than 30 days must register with the Mongolia Immigration Agency in Ulaanbaatar within the first seven days of arrival. Visitors who fail to register and who stay longer than 30 days, even for reasons beyond their control, will be stopped at departure, temporarily denied exit, and fined._” The reference is quite old, not sure if it’s still valid. Maybe you can go visit them and ask?

Comment: *so I hesitate to ask them and risk being suspected of wanting to abuse the system* => ask from a throwaway email?

Comment: @JonathanReez, good idea.

Comment: @jcaron, Yes, the embassy page also said that.  If and when I go, it will definitely be longer than thirty days.  So I would register.  But the question helps decide what to do at the end of the visa-exempt ninety days.  Probably wouldn't know before the third month whether I'd be satisfied with ninety days.  Mongolia is bigger than Spain, and my seventeen months in Spain weren't enough.

Comment: Another issue is some text hard to understand that sounds like if I'm exploring the whole country I would have to keep re-registering everywhere I go.  Sounds contrary to Wikipedia's description of Mongolia being rather free.  Wikipedia also says they have religious freedom, but a warning on the embassy website makes me wonder.

Comment: @WGroleau Many countries require that of foreigners (Italy, for example). Typically the registration is taken care of by the hotelier if you are staying in hotels. If you are staying in private accommodation someone would have to take care of the paperwork.

Comment: Why not just just get a visa? That seems like the most straightforward solution. "They already told me that to stay longer than ninety days, one must get a visa before arrival"

Comment: @Ozzy, Not completely clear, but I think coming in with a visa requires a planned departure and may require showing evidence of a ticket for that date on arrival.  I know the strategy of having a refundable ticket to cancel afterward.  (And I've never been asked for one at countries that supposedly require it.)  But if I can skip having to do that, it would be convenient.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I would likely use hostels or AirBNB or even wild camping when away from cities (yes, I am aware of the climate).